# adobe illustrator script- check if swatch color is on list

Tags: colors, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to make a script that will go through the swatches list and will search for a swatch named "Line".
if it will not be found I want to add it but if it already been found I want the script to be ignored.

this is what I did so far, the problem is that if it finds a swatch named "Line" it will create a new pink color for some reason.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

for (i = 0; i < doc.swatches.length; i++)
{
   if (doc.swatches[i].name != "Line")
   {
       var newSpot = doc.spots.add();

        var newColor = new CMYKColor();
        newColor.cyan = 100;
        newColor.magenta = 100;
        newColor.yellow = 100;
        newColor.black = 100;

        newSpot.name = "Line";
        newSpot.colorType = ColorModel.SPOT;
        newSpot.color = newColor;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to pick the color by its name first and create a new color only if there is the error:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

try { var color = doc.swatches.getByName('Line') }

catch(e) {

    var newColor = new CMYKColor();
        newColor.cyan    = 100;
        newColor.magenta = 100;
        newColor.yellow  = 100;
        newColor.black   = 100;

    var newSpot = doc.spots.add();
        newSpot.name      = 'Line';
        newSpot.colorType = ColorModel.SPOT;
        newSpot.color     = newColor;
}
```